# Mysql -- Use a secondary subquery if and only if the first subquery returned empty

Tags: mysql, sql

Given two subquery tables t1 and t2, how can I return t2 if and only if t1 returned empty rows?

**Edit:** Added example

T1

```
SELECT * 
  FROM common_table 
 WHERE language_id = 1
```

T2

```
SELECT * 
  FROM common_table 
 WHERE language_id = 2
```

Basically what I am doing is that in case the T1 return empty rows, I would like it to execute T2 and return those rows. Now, I am fully aware that I can do this in PHP but the query is a subquery and I would rather let SQL (***not PHP***) code handle it.

Comment: SQL is not a programming language.

Comment: Can you post the actual SQL statement you're trying to modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MSSQL I can do something like

```
If EXISTS (SELECT * FROM common_table WHERE language_id = 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM common_table WHERE language_id = 1
END ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM common_table WHERE language_id = 2
END
```

Should be the same in mySQL or similar

Comment: it is not sql though, it is t-sql.

Comment: The question specificly states mysql, but this does not work in mysql. Interesting to know, but not sure why it is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select ...
From common_table
Where language_id = 1
    Or  (
        language_id = 2
        And Not Exists  (
                        Select 1
                        From common_table
                        Where language_id = 1
                        )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

My MySql knowledge is a bit rusty and I think this should work.

```
SELECT * FROM common_table 
         WHERE language_id = 2 and 
               0 = ( SELECT count(*) FROM common_table 
                                     WHERE language_id = 1
                   ) ;
```

Comment: +1 I think an improvement might be `... WHERE (language_id = 1) OR (language_id = 2 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM common_table WHERE language_id = 1))`.  In my testing that gives all `lang_id` 1 records if there are any, else all `lang_id` 2, and the EXISTS might be more efficient than the COUNT.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM common_table 
 WHERE language_id = 1
UNION
SELECT * 
  FROM common_table 
 WHERE language_id = 2
       AND NOT EXISTS (
                       SELECT * 
                         FROM common_table AS T2 
                        WHERE T2.language_id = 1
                      );
```